# How do I use workers with node_modules?

Tags: worker, import-maps

I have in my project folder:

```
index.html
src
resources
node_modules
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>WebGPU App</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#"> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" typ="text/css" href="resources/css/style.css">       

        <script type="importmap"> { 
            "imports": { 
                "three": "/node_modules/three/build/three.module.js",
                "three/addons/": "/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/",
                "three/nodes": "/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/nodes/Nodes.js" 
            } 
        }     
        </script> 
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="container"></div>
        <script type="module" src="./src/index.js"></script>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

I have all my scripts in the src folder. I use one of the scripts as an import library

src/three-defs.js

```
import * as THREE from 'three';

import { OrbitControls } from 'three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import { CopyShader } from 'three/addons/shaders/CopyShader.js';
import { RenderPass } from 'three/addons/postprocessing/RenderPass.js';
import { ShaderPass } from 'three/addons/postprocessing/ShaderPass.js';
import { EffectComposer } from 'three/addons/postprocessing/EffectComposer.js';

import WebGPU from 'three/addons/capabilities/WebGPU.js';           
import WebGPURenderer from 'three/addons/renderers/webgpu/WebGPURenderer.js';

import { ShaderNode, MeshBasicNodeMaterial, texture, vec2, vec3, vec4, uv, color, wgslFn, tslFn, attribute, uniform, storage, positionWorld, normalLocal, normalWorld } from 'three/nodes';


export {THREE, WebGPU, WebGPURenderer, OrbitControls, RenderPass, ShaderPass, EffectComposer, CopyShader, ShaderNode, MeshBasicNodeMaterial, texture, color, vec2, vec3, vec4, wgslFn, tslFn, uv, attribute, uniform, storage, positionWorld, normalLocal, normalWorld};
```

If I import "three.module.js" without importmap it works.
Can it be that workers cannot see the importmap in index.html and therefore cannot import THREE?
I don't have any error messages, but you rarely get them if workers don't work because workers run independently of the main code.

if I do it like this in the worker it works:

```
//import {THREE} from 'three-defs.js';
import * as THREE from "../node_modules/three/build/three.module.js';
```

Does anyone have experience in dealing with import maps and workers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Node.js if needed from https://nodejs.org. This will allow us to use npm and run JavaScript outside the browser.

1. Open a terminal/command prompt. This is where we will run all the commands.
2. Initialize the Vite project:

```
npm create vite@latest my-threejs-project -- --template vanilla
```

This scaffolds a new project using Vite, a build tool that makes development easier. We pass the --template vanilla flag to indicate we want a basic JavaScript project setup.
3. Install dependencies when prompted. This will install Vite and other packages needed for the project template.
4. Navigate into the project folder:

```
cd my-threejs-project
```

This puts us inside the project directory we just created.
5. Install Three.js:

```
npm install three
```

This installs the three.js library we will use for 3D graphics.
6. Open src/main.js and import Three.js. This imports the library into
our JavaScript code.

Create scene, camera, renderer, and cube objects using Three.js constructors. This sets up a basic 3D scene.

```js
import * as THREE from 'three';

const scene = new THREE.Scene();

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(cube);

camera.position.z = 5;

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
  cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

animate();
```

Animate the cube by rotating it each frame.
Render the scene with the renderer and camera. This will draw the 3D graphics.

7. Run the dev server:

```
npm run dev
```

This starts the Vite development server so we can view the rendered scene in the browser.

Now when you go to http://localhost:5173, you should see the rotating cube!